# Java black jack game not working. Something todo with conditions

Tags: java, syntax, conditional-statements

Hi so I'm trying to make a black jack game but its not working. I believe  the logic is correct so perhaps its a syntax error?
There are two players Alice and bob. Players draw until 17. There are 5 possible outcomes
Alice wins. 
Bob wins. 
Alice busts Bob wins. 
Bob busts Alice wins. 
No one wins.

```
public class TweentyOne {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Player p1 = new Player("Bob");
       Player p2 = new Player("Alice");
       findWinner(p1, p2);
   }

   public static void findWinner(Player p1, Player p2){

       if(p1.showHand() > p2.showHand() && p1.showHand() <= 21){
           System.out.println(p1.getName() + " wins");
           System.out.println(p1.showHand());
           System.out.println(p2.showHand());
       }

       else if(p1.showHand() <= 21 && p2.showHand() > 21){
             System.out.println(p2.getName() + " busts. " + p1.getName() + " wins");
             System.out.println(p1.showHand());
           System.out.println(p2.showHand());
       }

       else if(p2.showHand() > p1.showHand() && p2.showHand() <= 21){
           System.out.println(p2.getName() + " wins");
           System.out.println(p1.showHand());
           System.out.println(p2.showHand());
       }

       else if(p2.showHand() <= 21 && p1.showHand() > 21){
           System.out.println(p1.getName() + " busts. " + p2.getName() + " wins");
           System.out.println(p1.showHand());
           System.out.println(p2.showHand());
       }

       else{
           System.out.println("No one wins");
           System.out.println(p1.showHand());
           System.out.println(p2.showHand());
       }
    }
}

class Player{

    private String name;
    private int hand;

    public Player(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int showHand(){

        int someHand = 0;

        while(someHand < 17)
        {   
            hand = (int) (Math.random() * 13 + 1);
            someHand += hand;
        }

        return someHand;
    }
}
```

The print statements are just there for me to check what they are actually drawing each time.

Comment: "its not working" — is there an exception? a compile error? Is it producing the wrong output?

Comment: Does it compile?  If yes, then it's not a syntax error; if no, you will be told what the syntax error(s) is(are).

Comment: its producing the wrong output. For example.. i set a condition if (p1.showHand() > p2.showHand() && p1.showHand() <= 21) how ever the output was Bob wins  17    20

Comment: When in that case it should have printed Alice wins

Comment: Dude: does `Player`'s `showHand()` method **generate a new hand** _every time_ you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (p1.showHand() > p2.showHand() && p1.showHand() <= 21)
```

here `p1.showHand()` gives you some Hand, when you execute it again after the `&&`, it will calculate some new, other hand.

Save both hands in variables at the beginning, then replace the method calls in your ifs with those variables, that should do the trick

Comment: Yes, `showHand()` has to be called only once per player per game, as it deals new cards. Maybe two methods `dealHand()` and `getHand()`.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, calling `Player.showHand()` generates a new hand. Either call the method only once per round and store it in a variable, or rather implement `showHand()` in a way that it only *displays* a previously dealt hand and does not deal a new one.

Your question however mentions BlackJack but the mechanism of generating new hands does not reflect this. So to make this more like actual BlackJack - how about creating a `Deck` object that holds `Card` objects and has a `Card drawCard()` method which the `Player` calls. `Player` can then have a `List` of cards that he drew. Randomly generating numbers as you do when calling `showHand()` does not reflect the nature of BlackJack.